# Getting Chrome remote debugging to detect a Galaxy Tab 1

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, debugging

I've got an html bug that, so far, appears only on a Samsung Galaxy Tab 1 and I'd like to inspect the html elements to diagnose the problem.
I have activated developer options on the tablet and activated USB debugging.

I have previously also followed the instructions on this page...
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/
...but the 'remote devices' tab (accessed from dev tools menu > more tools > remote devices) does not detect the connected tablet.

**EDIT**
I have downloaded the Android/tools and Android/platform-tools and, as instructed, extracted them to my C drive. I connect the Galaxy Tablet via a usb cable, open a command line from the platform-tools directory and run 'adb.exe'. I then run 'adb devices'. The command line tells me 'daemon not running. starting it now at tcp:5037'. But no devices are listed, and in Chrome dev tools I get no devices listed when I click the menu icon > more tools > remote devices.

I have also switched the tablet's USB connection type from MTP to PTP (camera). This has made no difference.

I can access files on the tablet through windows. I just don't see it listed either in the command line with 'adb devices' or in Chrome dev tools, menu > more tools > remote devices.

**ANOTHER EDIT**
This may or may not be important, but when I plug in the tablet I get a warning that 'device driver software was not successfully installed'. I can still access files on the tablet via windows. The tablet appears twice in Device Manager; Once, under 'Portable Devices' where 'properties' tells me it is working properly and secondly under 'Other Devices' where 'properties' tells me it doesn't have a driver installed. I have installed various drivers and tried to track down the correct driver from Samsung, without luck.

What am I doing wrong? Any ideas gladly received!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I have FINALLY managed to install the correct driver - at least one that works.
From device manager I right-clicked the tablet listed under 'Other Devices', selected 'update driver' > 'Browse my computer for driver software' > 'Let me pick from a list...' and then happened to find and choose the SAMSUNG Android ADB Interface from there.
Hopefully that is helpful to someone else...

Comment: I have Samsung Galaxy Tablet A, I also tried to follow the [official google instructions](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging) and they didn't work, where did you download the driver from and how can I ensure it is the correct one?  I chatted with Samsung and they said to install Smart Switch from http://www.samsung.com/au/support/smartswitch/img/Smart_Switch_PC.zip and that that would install the required driver - I did that and can copy and move files across etc but no device shows up in chrome developer tools on PC.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not sure at what point (in the sequence of various downloads I made) the SAMSUNG Android ADB option appeared in the list of driver options, but I'd recommend downloading the Android SDK and seeing if that provides the SAMSUNG Android ADB option for you.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I posted my solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45560715/1063287