# No devices detected when remote debugging in Chrome Developer Tools from Windows 7 Enterprise to Samsung Galaxy Tab A

Tags: windows-7, remote-debugging, samsung-galaxy

I am having problems with a web application on Chrome in [Samsung Galaxy Tab A](http://www.samsung.com/au/support/model/SM-P585YZKAXSA/).

I want to troubleshoot them with Chrome's `Developer Tools`.

On tablets you do not have access to Chrome's `Developer Tools`, so you need to set up `Remote Debugging`.

The process, [according to Google's official documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging), should essentially be:

**1)** Install the required driver on the PC so the tablet can be recognised.

**2)**  Connect the tablet to the PC via USB cable.

**2)**  On PC, go to `Chrome > Developer Tools > Menu > More Tools > Remote devices`

The tablet is not showing up as a device in developer tools in chrome on PC.

**What I've Tried**

I chatted to Samsung and they said to install [Smart Switch PC_Setup.exe](http://www.samsung.com/au/support/smartswitch/img/Smart_Switch_PC.zip) which would install driver so that Android device can be recognised.

As that didn't work I followed various post suggestions and installed:

- `SAMSUNG_USB_Driver_for_Mobile_Phones.zip (15.3MB)` from [here](http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/others/android-usb-driver-for-windows)
- `SDK Platform-Tools for Windows (7.16MB)` from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools.html)
- `sdk-tools-windows-3859397 (132MB)` from the bottom of the page [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html)

All of these contain `exe` files that I don't know how to use - if I double click them they just open and close a terminal.

**Desired Behavior**

To have tablet show as a device in Chrome developer tools.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This was my solution to show device in Chrome Developer Tools:

**1)**  Download SDK Platform-Tools for Windows (7.16MB) from [here](http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/others/android-usb-driver-for-windows).

**2)**  Extract zip file.

**3)**  In Windows terminal run your equivalent of:

```
D:\Users\You\path_to_extracted_folder\adb.exe devices
```

At first I got:

```
[5203253125 - long number] unauthorised
```

And then I think I unplugged and replugged USB cable from tablet and there was a prompt on the tablet:

```
Allow USB Debugging?
The computer's RSA key fingerprint is:
blah blah etc
```

to which I click `OK`

And I can now see device in Chrome Developer Tools!

Comment: I couldn't find the `SDK Platform-Tools for Windows` from your link. The only thing there is Samsung's USB Driver for Windows.  Did the platform tools move somewhere?

Comment: BTW, I did try the `USB Driver for Windows` that Samsung makes available at the linked page, but that didn't help me remote debug my Samsung S7 device.

Comment: I think this is purely coincidental, but after I installed and uninstalled Samsung's `USB Driver for Windows` from here http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/others/android-usb-driver-for-windows (`SAMSUNG_USB_Driver_for_Mobile_Phones.zip (15.3MB)` to be exact), Chrome's dev tools detected my device. Not sure what made this work. It could have been the numerous times I connected and disconnected the cable.  Not sure though.

Comment: Yes, interestingly installing the USB Driver for Windows and then un-installing it immediately afterward forced the prompt on the android to allow permission for my PC to remotely debug, which I agreed to and now it shows up.

Comment: @Bungler Interesting that you experienced the same thing as me. Could this be a repeatable fix? Good to know for the future. :-)

Comment: installed the driver, nothing happened... uninstalled and all of the sudden got the finger print alert and it started working :)

Comment: The SDK Platform Tools are available at https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools.html

Comment: Worked perfectly fine on my Galaxy S10. Thanks

Comment: This worked for me after doing the adb command which seemed to restart the daemon.  After that the tablet popped up the 'allow debugging' command.

Answer (score 29):

To get my Samsung S7 to connect, I did the following.

1. Download Samsung's USB Driver for Windows from here: http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/others/android-usb-driver-for-windows
2. Install the driver
3. Uninstall the driver. It's important to do this step, as your device won't connect until you uninstall. Strange, I know!

I initially reported this solution in the comments section [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45560325/no-devices-detected-when-remote-debugging-in-chrome-developer-tools-from-windows/45560715#comment80586160_45560715) but I didn't think it was a legitimate solution. I've since been able to reproduce this on 2 Windows 10 Pro devices and others have also confirmed.

**2019-05-10 Update**

After a Windows Update, this stopped working so I went through the process outlined above again. Installed driver then uninstalled driver and everything started working again.

Comment: LOLOL, I can NOT believe that worked.

Thanks for the answer, and thanks for nothing, Samsung.

Comment: ok, that is  amazing, i have no words... it worked :). Thank you very much for this workaround

Comment: UNBELIEVABLE, also works with the S8, the black art of inspecting devices continues year after year...

Comment: Man, this shouldn't work. But id does. Not sure to be disgusted or amazed. Probably both...

Comment: Can confirm it still works! I had installed the USB drivers and forgotten about them. After uninstalling, it worked immediately.

Comment: It is quite sad but this procedure worked for me as well. Windows 10, Galaxy tab 4. Congratulations for all envolved into.

Comment: Sad to say, but here we are. This still works for the S8.

Comment: This shouldn't work, but it does. Had been looking for a solution for some days now!

Comment: Spent hours and finally, this worked. I'm still in shock.

Answer (score 0):

I find the best approach these days is to *not* use vendor-provided drivers.  They're often difficult to install, and frequently come bundled with tools that aren't required and which get in the way.  I tend to use the "universal" driver that can be downloaded from http://adbdriver.com/, which comes with a very simple, easy-to-use installer: run the installer, it gives a list of phones or tablets attached to your computer via USB, press a button and it installs the driver for the selected device.

Answer (score 0):

**Update for 05-2019**

See the comment from Johnny Oshika in the approved answer. This works every time for me.

> I think this is purely coincidental, but after I installed and
>   uninstalled Samsung's USB Driver for Windows from here
>   developer.samsung.com/galaxy/others/…
>   (SAMSUNG_USB_Driver_for_Mobile_Phones.zip (15.3MB) to be exact),
>   Chrome's dev tools detected my device. Not sure what made this work.
>   It could have been the numerous times I connected and disconnected the
>   cable. Not sure though. – Johnny Oshika Oct 18 '17 at 21:17